Error for the nullptr in smart ponter initializatin
ALL,
Using MSVC 2017.
When I had the code like this:
class Foo
{
private:
    LibraryObject *m_library;
};

my code compiled fine.
But when I tried to do it like this:
class Foo
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<LibraryObject> m_library( nullptr );
};

ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/how-to-create-and-use-shared-ptr-instances?view=msvc-170 Example 1 at the end f the code, I started getting the error:
error C2059: syntax error: 'nullptr'

Cold someone please explain why am I getting the error?
TIA!!!

Try std::shared_ptr<LibraryObject> m_library{ nullptr }; or std::shared_ptr<LibraryObject> m_library = nullptr;.

You can't do embedded initialization of class member variables like that until later C++ versions.  Remove the "nullptr" and initialize it in your constructor.

std::shared_ptr is nullptr by default, you don't need to initialize it with nullptr.

@TimRoberts C++ has supported this kind of inlined member initialization since C++11, which is the same version that introduced nullptr and shared_ptr

@songyuanyao, the MSDN page I reference clearly use braces...

@3CxEZiVlQ, this doesn't answer my question - why am I getting the error...

It does answer.

@3CxEZiVlQ, ok I check the answer given as the reason for closure and I understand now. Thx.

Similar reason to Why can't the default constructor be called with empty brackets? except with argument.

You think the type matters because you changed two things at once. LibraryObject *m_library (nullptr); also would not compile, while std::shared_ptr<LibraryObject> m_library; would.

the example in the link is using the member initializer list. You are using an in-class / default initializer. THose are two distinct and different features. Member initializer list works with () but default initializer not.

this answer explains the difference
